# Jquery tabs implementation - SharePoint 2010

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010

We are facing an issue with Jquery tabs implementation.

If we are using below code in a simple new item form, it is working fine.

But if we are using it in a new item form( in which Jquery tab used), it is not working at all.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[title='FromDate']").change(function () {
        alert('From date');
    });
});
```

To create Jquery tab, we referred below url.

http://amitphule.blogspot.hk/2011/08/change-look-and-feel-of-sharepoint-page.html

Comment: which error ? What are the expected and actual behaviors?

Comment: try `.live("change", function ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use tabid in selector.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#tabID input[title='FromDate']").change(function () {

    alert('From date');
});

});
```

Comment: I tried below modified code. My div ID for tab is 'tabs-2'. But still it is not working. Is this correct way of implementation? $(document).ready(function () { $("#tabs-2 input[title='FromDate']").change(function () { alert('From date'); }); });

Comment: I tried this code on my local. And it works. :| <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#tabs-2 input[title='FromDate']").change(function() {
   alert('From date');
 }); 
});
</script> Try adding a class to your input.<input class="FromDate" name="" type="text" /> Use the class as following codes: <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#tabs-2 .FromDate').change(function() {
   alert('From date');
 }); 
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

If tab-2 is ajaxed in or created after the jquery is run, then the .change wont work unless you use [**.live**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to maintain the initiation of new elements added to the document.

Try making use of .live and see if it makes a diffence as follows:

```
$("input[title='FromDate']").live("change", function () { 
    alert('From date'); 
});
```